# DisplayPort converter HDMI for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: hdmi

I tried to use a DisplayPort converter to HDMI but, it did not work. I have my monitor with DP port and my RP3 with a HDMI. I am confused about so many resources on the internet that do not provide a clearly response to my question. Can anybody explain me this?

Answer (score 1):

### DP - DisplayPort

The cheaper adaptors (in the £5 - £20 GBP range) are **passive** adaptors which are designed for DP output to HDMI input (the opposite to what you want/need).

There are **active** adaptors (in the £50 - £100 GBP range) that do the HDMI output to DP input. These typically need or come with a power supply.

You might want to try a HDMI to DVI cable if your monitor support DVI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, my monitor does not have a DVI port it has a VGA port but. I do not have the converter. I believe, I need an active adaptors that do the HDMI output to DP input like you mention. But, here in Mexico you will see a many stores with cheap devices like this that in most of the cases they do not work or just do not mention something more. If I cannot find a good answer from the store we I bought it, I will try with the VGA. thanks